# web.py sessions: AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, web.py

I just ran this simple code snippet provided by the wiki, because I couldn't get sessions working:

```
import web
web.config.debug = False
urls = (
    "/count", "count",
    "/reset", "reset"
)
app = web.application(urls, locals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'count': 0})

class count:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return str(session.count)

class reset:
    def GET(self):
        session.kill()
        return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But it results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 228, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 411, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 387, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "temp.py", line 12, in GET
    session.count += 1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/session.py", line 71, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._data, name)
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Is webpy not compatible with 2.7.3? I'm running this on the internal webserver of webpy. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I got that error when I left out "web.config.debug = False"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.count += 1` is equal to `session.count = session.count + 1` so `session.count` must exist for this to work.

Add the following check to make it work:

```
if 'count' not in session:
    session.count = 0
session.count += 1
```

There is also another way which is even shown in the [*very simple session simple example*](http://webpy.org/sessions/simpleexample) of the docs:

```
try:
    s.click += 1
except AttributeError:
    s.click = 1
```

Comment: Isn't this done by the initializer in the line `session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'count': 0})`?

Comment: I was wondering the same question. What is the point of the initializer if we need to initiate this session parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the trick of *try...except* also i'm not convinced it's the best way to do so (not clean at all).
Like previously said, Session constructor offer a way to initialize the session's variable.

I'm not really sure we can rely on the "[very simple session simple example](http://webpy.org/sessions/simpleexample)".

First, we hardly have any explication on the purpose of various variablse. For instance, what is the purpose the *db_parameter* dict ?

Last but not least, it needs a serious update. The provided code simply didn't work with the actual framework.
There is simply no *web.ctx.session*.

By the way, I implemented a simple counter like in the example.
The displayed error you had is due to a drastic change in the Session's API.
You cannot just call "counter" from your session. 
That would be more smthg like that: **session.store.store_instance.get('counter')** .Where store_instance is either a shelf or a db.
Like i said, the official documentation needs a serious update.

That said, I noticed that this is not the same for the docstring. To progress i start Ipython and i see every posibilities I have.
I know it's pure guessing but naming is good so we can figure out what to do.

I will submit my example to the team of web.py so they can update the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

Until my pull request get accepted on GitHub, i post the snippet of code illustrating the use of a simple incrementor:

```
import web
import shelve


urls = (
    '/add', 'counter',
    '/reset', 'reset'
)

shelf = shelve.open('session')
shelfStore = web.session.ShelfStore(shelf)
app = web.application(urls, globals())
s = web.session.Session(app, shelfStore)

class counter:        
    def GET(self):
        numberToAdd = web.input().get('number')
        if not numberToAdd:
            numberToAdd = 1
        try:
            print  numberToAdd
            s.store.shelf["count"] += int(numberToAdd)
        except Exception:
            s.store.shelf["count"] = 1
        return s.store.shelf.get("count")


class reset:
    def GET(self): 
        s.store.shelf.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the python version. I had the same problem and I solved it when I executed 2.7 version of python. Just doing > python2.7 code.py and the sessions works perfectly.
It's a pity that the doc to web.py is very poor.